# Trying to access a private Linked List in another class file

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list, compare, private

I'm having an issue bringing over a private Linked List from one class that I need to sort through in another class.

```
private LinkedList<Interest> interests = new LinkedList<Interest>();
```

From here, this is the comparing method I'm using.

```
    private Member their;
    private int score;

    LinkedList<Interest> stu1Interests;
    LinkedList<Interest> stu2Interests;
    their = getTheir();
    boolean hasInterest = false;
    stu2Interests = their.getInterests();
    stu1Interests = my.getInterests();

    for (Interest theirInterest : stu2Interests)
    {

        for (Interest myInterest : stu1Interests)
        {
            if (theirInterest.getTopic().toLowerCase().equals(myInterest.getTopic().toLowerCase()))
            {
                score += theirInterest.getLevel() * myInterest.getLevel();
                hasInterest = true;
            }
        }


        if (hasInterest == false)
            score += (int) theirInterest.getLevel() / 2;

        hasInterest = false;
    }
```

I originally thought my issues were coming from a problem where I had these methods in the constructor, but creating a separate method yielded the same results. I kept getting NullPointerExceptions and InvocationTargetExceptions. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: The purpose of a _private_ attributes is to not be shared and accessed by other classes. You can pass the interests  List as a parameter of your method. May be share the whole code, we can not help you more with this. PS: Use List instead of LinkedList for your variable/ attributes declaration.

Comment: Try to debug. Most probably its due to some uninitialized object. And to access  LinkedList create its getters/setters